# How is it possible for monosomies to occur?

Tags: genetics, cell-biology, meiosis, sexual-reproduction

I was taught in biology class that a cell dies if it doesn't have at least one copy of a chromosome "type". If this is the case, that means that:

1. Zygotes without a copy of a specific chromosome (for example chromosome 21) die.
   But this would *also* mean:
2. Gametes without a copy of a specific chromosome would also die.

If this is the case, how is it possible for monosomies to occur? Wouldn't there have to be at least one haploid cell with (n-1) chromosomes when fertilization occurs?

Comment: Your assumption #2 is wrong.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Ok; can you please elaborate on this and turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gametes cannot be compared to regular (id est, somatic) cells for two main reasons:

1. Their lifetime and...
2. Their gene expression.

In human beings, gametes have a very short lifetime. Supposing the nondisjunction happened at meiosis I (which is the worst case scenario), a "nulissomic female gamete"<sup>1</sup> has to be alive for some days, from the end of the dictyotene to the fertilisation. The male gamete would have to stay alive for a little more time, some weeks, from the spermatogonium stage to the end of meiosis. Those are not big time spans.

But the most important reason is that gametes are basically a structure to "deliver" genes. They normally don't express the genes they have, at least not as a somatic cell would do. Sperm cells, for instance, have [densely packed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protamine) chromosomes and gene expression, [if any](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0127007), is little and poorly understood.

Thus, the problem in your reasoning lies in assumption #2:

> Gametes without a copy of a specific chromosome would also die.

Gametes lacking a given chromosome can and do exist, and they form aneuploid zygotes.

<sub>Note 1: the name "gamete" here is a wrong choice, since a primary oocyte is not a gamete, as it is the name "nullisomic", which doesn't apply to haploid cells.</sub>

Comment: Had I more points I would bounty this answer. Signed  – a technical editor